# Null sequences - proof writing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here are the basic null sequences

(1) {$\frac{1}{n^p}$} for p>0;

(2) {$c^n$} for $|c| <1$

(3) {$n^pc^n$} for p>0 and $|c| <1$

(4) {$\frac{c^n}{n!}$} for any real c

(5) {$\frac{n^p}{n!}$} for p > 0

I have to prove {$\frac{n^{10}10^n}{n!}$} is a null sequence using the basic null sequences

My proof: $\frac{n^{10}}{n!}*10^n$ using the 5th rule we know $\frac{n^{10}}{n!}$ is null.

Now, we have $0*10^n = 0 $.
Hence, {$\frac{n^{10}10^n}{n!}$} is null.

Is this okay?

Comment: That's not a valid argument. By the same reasoning, $\{\frac{n^3}{n^3}\}$ is a null sequence because by rule (1) $\{\frac{1}{n^3}\}$ is a null sequence and $0\cdot n^3 = 0$. Can you see that that doesn't work?

Comment: Would this be valid if 10^n was a constant instead?

Comment: Yes, then it would be valid. Or if it were a null sequence.

Comment: for example $6*\frac{n^{10}}{n!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you get an indeterminate form. Rather you can write

$$\frac{n^{10}10^n}{n!}=\frac{11^n}{n!}\times n^{10}\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^n$$
and use $(3)$ and $(4)$.